# C- getchar() re-read characters?

Tags: c, getchar

is there a way that I can read a character with getchar() and read the same character with another getchar()?

for example the user gives 5 and the first getchar() reads 5 and then the second getchar() re-reads the 5.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice that `ungetc` can be guaranteed for maximum 1 character... i.e. it can be only used to support one character peek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ungetc()` to put the character back in the input stream.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Type something: ");
    int c = getchar();
    printf("Ok, you typed '%c'. Putting it back...\n", c);
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    printf("Reading it again...\n");
    c = getchar();
    printf("Still '%c'. Putting it back again...\n", c);
    ungetc(c, stdin);
    printf("Reading it again...\n");
    c = getchar();
    printf("Still '%c'!\n", c);
}
```

Running it:

```
Type something: smackflaad
Ok, you typed 's'. Putting it back...
Reading it again...
Still 's'. Putting it back again...
Reading it again...
Still 's'!
```

Comment: can you please give me an example?